# Using Microsoft Graph API to update PasswordProfile (password reset)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to create a tool to handle password resets (user forgot their password).  We’ve applied permissions to the AAD app used for [password resets per the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update).

Getting the error:

```
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
```

Should this be possible using the [Client Credentials Grant flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reset user passwords using Application permission scopes (i.e. scopes use for the `client_credentials` grant). Per the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update):

> When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following permission is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

The [`Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#directory-permissions) is only available as a Delegated permission scope.

Comment: Hey Marc... can you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56546947/114029